# Which leg does the each animation start with? ( Unity - Blend Tree - Locomotion System )

Tags: unity, animation

I am creating an animation pack for creating a movement system. I'm afraid I will make the animations wrong, as I think it is important that each animation starts from a specific leg, i.e. the legs that will be in front of the character at the beginning of the clip.

Can you tell me - Which leg does the each animation start with?

[image]